# Is Akka.net synchronus in processing messages, dont await in an event handler?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, akka.net

My understanding of akka.net is that a message is processed one at a time from its mailbox, it does not process multiple messages at a time for a given actor.

What does this mean in terms of using the await keyword, I don't think it adds any value in the actor pattern world.

I understand that akka.net solves multi-threading issues to allow you to create distributed systems.

ReceiveAsync event handlers, what is the purpose of using them? And is there any need to use await and async methods in an actor.

Answer (score 3):

Akka actor model allows you to express asynchronous workflows as a state machine. In similar fashion, C# compiler builds code responsible for handling an async/await code. So yes, you could build a fully asynchronous code in Akka.NET without ever using async/await - most of the akka.net internally works like that. There are several points there to keep in mind regarding `ReceiveAsync`, the biggest one is about reentrancy.

### Reentrancy

I'll use a concept of a **workflow** here - you can imagine a workflow as a multi-step process, which realizes some kind of a request:

1. In message-based systems (like Akka, but also NServiceBus Sagas or Azure Durable Functions) workflow can be realized as a state machine being a combination of different triggers (messages) and processing blocks (message handlers).
2. In async/await you can represent triggers as awaiters and processing blocks as parts of code between one await call and the next one.

**By default all Akka actors are reentrant** - this means, that when you have to process a workflow, that consists of many steps (quite often you may recognize them by using `Self.Tell(nextStepSignal)`), it may accept new incoming requests in the meantime, simply because there's no distinction between message starting a new workflow and the one, which signals a next step of the workflow already in progress. So essentially an actor is able to execute many parallel workflows, while still processing each block on a single thread.

While this is useful property for most of the time, sometimes you want to have an actor in a fixed state for the entire time necessary to process a workflow. When using standard approach, in Akka this can be achieved as a combination of stashing and Become/Unbecome behavior change - we change actor's behavior and start to stash messages uncorrelated with that behavior, and once the workflow finishes, we go back to previous behavior and unstash awaiting messages.

**The difference in `ReceiveAsync` is that it makes an actor non-reentrant until the async message handler finishes**. How it's achieved? Simply, and actor's mailbox is suspended until handler eventually returns a result. This means, that for that time actor won't process any new messages. This has several pros and cons.

Pros:

- Mostly it's easy to use with existing .NET libraries. Instead of building your own state machine, you let C# compiler generate it's own.
- You know that actor's state won't be altered by any other workflows being executed in parallel.
- You don't need stashing to keep things around. This is sometimes useful when combined with other features, like SmallestMailbox router option: *since stashing is actually picking elements from the actor's mailbox it will get more and more messages (as the one having the smallest mailbox) even thou it doesn't process them*.
- For some debugging cases you get clear stack traces.

Cons:

- Since actor is not able to process other requests, it has limited communicating capabilities with other actors. I.e. you can still use `Ask` for other actors, but this is more expensive option than `Tell`-based message exchange.
- In general Akka actors are optimized to take advantage of their reentrancy model, and using `ReceiveAsync` is considered to be slower option. However you need to make your own measures to decide what speed is satisfying to you.
- Since actor is non-reentrant, it won't process new messages until current workflow finishes. This means that actor may not process any new messages because it's waiting for a timeout to happen (or waiting forever if you didn't specified any timeout).
- When debugging a stateful component (such as an actor), a manually tailored state machine may tell you more than mile-long stack trace: simply because stack traces don't say much about actual state of the component that crashed.